# How to generate unique 10 digit alpha numeric values in Android?

Tags: android

How to generate unique id in android.. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Let's see, you'll need 10 digit alphanumeric, so that's around 60 bits?

```
UUID random = UUID.randomUUID();
long first64 = random.getLeastSignificantBits();
long last64 = random.getMostSignificantBits();
```

And there you have 128 random bits, which you can turn into an alpha-string.

Comment: I need to generate unique ID's for my application. When I used (UUID.randomUUID()).toString(), I am getting a code (thinking this will be unique), which is very lengthy.

Comment: Do you need to generate user-facing IDs, or internal ones? That is, does the ID need to be seen/read/copied by a human, or is it internal? If it's internal, UUID has the advantage of being "guaranteed" globally unique. For human-readable ones, you can take part of the UUID (preferably MSB) and turn them into alpha-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [UUID Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) of Android Documentation.

You may find useful the following to use: [UUIrandomUUID()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29)